# Unable to connect phone to normal Wifi networks after using corporate WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, networking, wpa2

I use my office network which is a Corporate WiFi set-up secured with 802.1x (and requires me to use my company credentials - Username and Password). But when I'm back home and try to connect my home WiFi router which is protected by WPA/WPA2 PSK security (which requires just a password), I can't get it connected automatically (even if I have the network remembered).

All I can do to fix it currently is;

- Restart my home router several times.
- Restart my phone for 2-3 times.
- Forget all remembered WiFi networks on phone.

and only after above steps it can connect, otherwise I get **Authentication Problem** as error if I try to connect. I'm on Android 4.2.1 (almost stock android, just some custom icons by vendor) device running on MediaTek chipset (MTK6589T), Micromax Canvas Magnus A117 to be specific.

While this same problem is with my other friends as well who use our company network at office in their phones (which are varied from Samsung, Sony, and even Nexus).

What can I do to avoid this daily hassle when I return home and connect home WiFi?

Comment: Is your router's network name the same as the one in the office? Something generic like "Netgear" or "WiFi" by any chance?

Comment: No, both networks have different SSIDs.

Comment: Are your WiFi passwords synching with Google maybe? You could have the list with "WorkWiFi" and that synchs, removing all the others. It's not likely, but I've had nothing but trouble with WiFi passwords on my devices, I lost ALL of them again yesterday for no apparent reason :(

Answer (score -1):

Disable Google sync (leak wifi passwords). If you have rooted smartphone try wifipass application (check wifi pass) and wifi analyzer (diff wifi connection attributes)